# Matrix operation, constructor problem

Tags: c++, constructor, matrix

I would like to put another question about matrix operations...

```
template <typename T>
struct TMatrix
{
    typedef std::vector < std::vector <T> > Type;
};


template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
    private:
            typename TMatrix <T>::Type items;       
            const unsigned int rows_count;          
            const unsigned int columns_count;   

    public:
             template <typename U>
             //Error, see bellow please
             Matrix ( const Matrix <U> &M ): 
                  rows_count ( M.getRowsCount() ), columns_count ( M.getColumnsCount() ), items ( M.getItems()){} 
             unsigned int getRowsCount() const {return rows_count;}
             unsigned int getColumnsCount() const {return columns_count;}
             typename TMatrix <T>::Type const & getItems () const {return items;}
             typename TMatrix <T>::Type & getItems ()  {return items;}
```

Compiling the code, the compiler stops here:

```
Matrix ( const Matrix <U> &M ):  
      rows_count ( M.getRowsCount() ), columns_count ( M.getColumnsCount() ), items ( M.getItems()){}  //Error
```

and shows the following error:

```
Error   79  error C2664: 'std::vector<_Ty>::vector(const std::allocator<_Ty> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const std::vector<_Ty>' to 'const std::allocator<_Ty> &'
```

But I do not know, why... Thanks again for your help...

**Updated question:**

Compiling the code

```
template <class T>
template <typename U>
Matrix <T> :: Matrix ( const Matrix <U> &M )
: rows_count ( M.getRowsCount() ), columns_count ( M.getColumnsCount() ), items ( M.getItems().begin(), M.getItems().end()){}
```

with the following result:

```
Error   132 error C2664: 'std::vector<_Ty>::vector(const std::allocator<_Ty> &)' : 
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const std::vector<_Ty>' to 'const std::allocator<_Ty> &'
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xmemory    208
```

Comment: Does it *have* to use a vector of vectors as the underlying container? Every row in your matrix is in a different part of RAM, potentially invalidating cache several times when iterating. Using a 1D sequence container internally makes everything so much easier.

Comment: @Cubbi: It also has the advantage that you can pass the 1D sequence container address to efficient routines for basic matrix operations (BLAS) or for more complex algorithms that you surely don't want to code yourself (LAPACK).

Comment: @Cubbi, @Alexandre - excuse my ignorance, but is a Matrix always a rectangle? Or can it have a jagged edge? (That is, is the row length constant amongst all rows?)

Answer (score 2):

Your templated constructor `Matrix<T>::Matrix<U>(const Matrix<U> &M)` is designed to construct a `Matrix<T>` given a `Matrix<U>`. It does this by invoking the constructor  `vector<vector<T>>(vector<vector<U>>)` in the initializer list.

The problem is that `std::vector` does not provide a mixed-type constructor.

I don't know how to solve this in the initializer list. You might do it in the body of the constructor. Here are updates to your public interface to allow this:

```
Matrix() : rows_count(), columns_count(), items() {}
template <typename U>
Matrix ( const Matrix <U> M ):
    rows_count ( M.getRowsCount() ), columns_count ( M.getColumnsCount() ), items ( ) {
    for(int i = 0; i < M.getItems().size(); i++) {
        items.push_back(std::vector<T>(M.getItems()[i].begin(),M.getItems()[i].end()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to `#include <vector>` at the top and a `};` at the end of the file. When I add these to the code, it compiles just fine on my computer.